# Options to integrate Version Control Systems and Issue Management systems

Tags: version-control, integration, policy, issue-tracking

Is there any other policy that any of you have implemented other than the ones given below?

- Valid Issue ID per commit. - To track changes made for a bug. Will help maintainability in the long run.
- Valid Issue status( Open or In-progress). - Why work on issue that are closed.
- Issue should be assigned to the user doing the commit. More users working on a single bug is a waste of resources.

The above mentioned policies might not work well for for the open source community as it enforces restrictions. But having policies like this would have more traceability in code thereby on-boarding new developers is much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tie a **merge strategy** with the ticket-related status of a commit.
Only commits which are:

- with an associated closed ("resolved") bug status
- **reviewed** (either code review or test), with the option to have that extra-step before closing or rejecting.

can be merge to certain branches meant to integrate all the fixes.